# shutting the app by removing notification

Tags: android, android-studio

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void showNotification(int playPauseBtn) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExoActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    Intent prevIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_PREVIOUS);
    PendingIntent prevPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, prevIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
    PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, playIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class).setAction(ACTION_NEXT);
    PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), HelperClass.getlist().get(position).getImg());
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID_2)
            .setSmallIcon(HelperClass.getlist().get(position).getImg())    //get thumbnail will have small icon pic
            .setLargeIcon(picture)
            .setContentTitle(HelperClass.getlist().get(position).getName())
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_previous_24, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24, "Play", playPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_baseline_skip_next_24, "Next", nextPendingIntent)
          //.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
          //.setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken()))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setC`your text`ontentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

This code creates Notification wherever this 'showNotification()' function is called but what if I want to shut the app by removing the notification?

Answer (score 0):

use [`setDeleteIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) method - when notification is removed you can send some broadcast to all your "contextual" ojects (e.g. `Activity`, `Service`)

note that there is also [`setOngoing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)) method, which will stick your notification and user won't be able to remove it "manually". then you can provide "kill" action button for this notification, which may behave exacly same as one created for `setDeleteIntent`. in that case don't forget to remove notification when user just leave/exit your app, when "kill" action pressed or in any other "usual" way